# Is there any way to export Subscriber by "Add Method" in exactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export

I would like to filter out subscriber who subscribed via "Web Collect" web form.

I tried the export function in the subscriber grid view, but it cannot export "AddMethod" column.

Then i try "query" at interaction, but it only support data extension but not subscription list.

Any one could give me suggestions to get the result?

Thanks!
Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query activities have access to subscriber data through Data Views. The ListSubscriber Data View has info on add method per list:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_listsubscribers/